# Linked lists in C++

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am trying to teach myself linked-lists with node structs and was hoping someone could help me with this. I would take input from the command line and it would make me a nested list and I could output it.

Example:

Input: "1 2 3 4 5" 
Output:"1 2 3 4 5"

There are two things I am having trouble with:
1) When I run the program I keep getting **warning: ‘typedef’ was ignored in this declaration [enabled by default]**
How can I get rid of this?

EDIT: I have changed this to `typedef struct Node* NodePtr;`

2) My code is not working properly. How can I fix this? I am trying to teach myself linked lists in C++.

```
typedef struct Node;
typedef Node* NodePtr;
struct Node{
    int x;
    NodePtr next;
};

int main ()
{
    int n;
    NodePtr head, ptr = NULL;
    head = ptr;
    while (cin >> n){
        ptr = new Node;
        ptr->x = n;
        ptr->next = NULL;
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }

    NodePtr bling = head;
    while(bling != NULL){
        cout << bling->x << endl;
        bling = bling->next;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Ideally what I want to do is to make a linked-list like the following.

```
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> NULL.
```

Comment: I think you meant `typedef struct Node {...} *NodePtr;` instead of the first two `typedef`s, unless you really want the `NodePtr` inside the structure, in which case you'd have to do it a little differently before.

Comment: By "My code is not working properly" what do you mean? Is there an error?

Comment: @Quirliom it does not work like it will not print out the data, which makes me think I am connecting the nodes properly

Comment: @chris I just want NodePtr to be typedef so I would not have to write "struct Node*" everywhere when defining a pointer of this type

Comment: @Masterminder, You don't. You only have to type `Node *` anyway.

Comment: ahh okay thank chris I just want to avoid the Node * period. So what you wrote should be the answer?

Comment: If you're looking for a [FIFO (first-in-first-out)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO) you should manage a tail and head pointer, pushing new nodes on the tail, pulling them off the head; aka. a *queue*.

Comment: @Masterminder, It seems there are more relevant problems. I'm afraid I didn't look too far past the typedef issue, so I'm unaware of what the real solution actually is.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, regarding the declaration of your structure and the pointer typedef you seem to want, there are a number of ways of doing this. The following will work in C or C++.

```
// declare NodePtr as a pointer to Node, currently an incomplete type
//  C and C++ both allow you to declare a pointer to damn-near anything
//  so long as there is an understanding of what it *will* be, in this
//  case, a structure called Node.
typedef struct Node *NodePtr;

// Now declare the structure type itself
struct Node
{
    int x;
    NodePtr next;
};
```

That said, I honestly *do not recommend doing this*. Most engineers want a *clear* and syntax-visible definition that screams to them, "THIS IS A POINTER!" You may be different. I, personally would simply prefer this:

```
struct Node
{
    int x;
    struct Node *next; // omit the 'struct' for C++-only usage
};
```

So long as you, and equally important, *other engineers reading your code*, understand your usage of `NodePtr` as a pointer-to-node, then go with what works best in your situation. Pointer type declaration is near-religious to some, so just keep that in mind. Some prefer seeing those asterisks (I being one), some may not (sounds like *you* =P).

Note: there is *one* place that using a `typedef`ed pointer-type can be beneficial in avoiding potential errors: **multiple variable declarations**. Consider this:

```
Node* a, b;     // declares one Node* (a), and one Node (b)
```

Having a `typedef struct Node *NodePtr;` allows this:

```
NodePtr a, b;   // declares two Node*; both (a) and (b)
```

If you spend enough time writing code in C the former of these will come back to bite you enough times you learn to not make that mistake, but it can still happen once in awhile.

---

**The Load Loop**

Regarding the load-loop for piecing together your list, you're not wiring up your list correctly, and frankly there are a million ways to do it, one being the one below. This does *not* require you to clean out "an extra node". Nor does it require any `if (head){} else{}` block structure to avoid said-same condition. Consider what we're really trying to do: create nodes and assign their addresses to the right pointers:

```
NodePtr head = NULL;     // always the head of the list.
NodePtr* ptr = &head;    // will always point to the next pointer to assign.
int n;
while (cin >> n)
{
    *ptr = new Node;
    (*ptr)->x = n;
    ptr = &(*ptr)->next;
}

// note this always terminates the load with a NULL tail.
(*ptr)->next = NULL;
```

---

**How It Works**

1. Initialize the head pointer to NULL
2. Initializer a Node pointer-pointer (yes a pointer to a pointer) to point to the head pointer. This pointer-to-pointer will always hold the address of the *target* pointer that is to receive the address of the next dynamic-allocated node. Initially, that will be the head pointer. In the above code, this pointer-to-pointer is the variable: `ptr`.
3. Begin the while-loop. For each value read, allocate a new node, saving it in the pointer that is pointed-to by `ptr` (thus the `*ptr`). On the first iteration this holds the address of the `head` pointer, so the `head` variable will get our new node allocation. On all subsequent iterations, it contains the address of the `next` pointer *of the last node inserted*. Incidentally, saving the address of this new target pointer is the *last* thing that is done in the loop before we move to the next allocation cycle.
4. Once the loop is complete, the *last* node inserted needs to have its `next` pointer set to NULL to ensure a properly terminated linked list. *This is mandatory*. We conveniently have a pointer to that pointer (the same one we've been using all this time), and thus we set the pointer it "points to" to NULL. Our list is terminated and our load is complete. Brain Food: What pointer will it be pointing *to* if the load loop never loaded any nodes? Answer: `&head`, which is exactly what we want (a `NULL` head pointer) if our list is empty.

---

**Design**

I hope this will help better explain how it works through three full iterations of the loop.

Initial configuration

```
      head ===> NULL;
ptr --^
```

After one iteration:

```
head ===> node(1)
          next
ptr ------^
```

After two iterations

```
head ===> node(1)
          next ===> node(2)
                    next
ptr ----------------^
```

After three iterations

```
head ===> node(1)
          next ===> node(2)
                    next ===> node(3)
                              next
ptr --------------------------^
```

If we stopped at three iterations, the final termination assignment (`*ptr = NULL;`), gives:

```
head ===> node(1)
          next ===> node(2)
                    next ===> node(3)
                              next ===> NULL;
ptr --------------------------^
```

Notice that `head` never changes once the first iteration is finished (it always points to the first node). Also notice that `ptr` always holds the address of the next pointer that is to be populated, which after the initial iteration (where it started as the address of our head pointer), will always be the address of the `next` pointer in the *last* node added.

I hope that gives you some ideas. It is worth noting that pairing these two pointers (the `head` pointer and the `ptr` pointer) into their own structure and having the appropriate management functions defines the textbook [*Queue*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_%28abstract_data_type%29); where one end is only for insertions (`ptr`) one is for extractions (`head`) and the container does *not* allow random access. There isn't much need for such a thing these days with the standard library container adapters like [`std::queue<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue), but it does provide an interesting adventure into a good use of pointer-to-pointer concepts.

---

**Complete Working Sample**

This sample just loads our queue with 20 elements, prints them, then cleans out the queue and exits. Adapt to your usage as needed (hint: like change the source of the incoming data perhaps)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// declare NodePtr as a pointer to Node, currently an incomplete type
//  C and C++ both allow you to declare a pointer to damn-near anything
//  so long as there is an understanding of what it *will* be, in this
//  case, a structure called Node.
typedef struct Node *NodePtr;

// Now declare the structure type itself
struct Node
{
    int x;
    NodePtr next;
};

int main()
{
    // load our list with 20 elements
    NodePtr head = NULL;
    NodePtr* ptr = &head;
    for (int n=1;n<=20;++n)
    {
        *ptr = new Node;
        (*ptr)->x = n;
        ptr = &(*ptr)->next;
    }

    // terminate the list.
    *ptr = NULL;

    // walk the list, printing each element
    NodePtr p = head;
    while (p)
    {
        cout << p->x << ' ';
        p = p->next;
    }
    cout << endl;

    // free the list
    while (head)
    {
        NodePtr victim = head;
        head = head->next;
        delete victim;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

Comment: Would this be correct as well to type def it so I could avoid the *?
typedef struct Node* NodePtr;
struct Node{
        int x;
        NodePtr next;
};

Comment: @Masterminder I'll update the head of this answer to reflect the structure definition I think you're having problems with. Most everyone else already has which was why I avoided it, but if you want it here as well I'll certainly provide it.

Comment: Thank you I am trying to run your code with my structure definiton and am getting a segmentation fault

Comment: @Masterminder then it is highly likely your structure is not declared correctly. see the updated post above, including both how to declare your structure and structure pointer, as well as the [complete working sample](http://ideone.com/SicI2y) at the end.

Comment: instead of ... NodePtr* ptr = &head; ... can i just do this? 
int n;
        NodePtr head, ptr;
        ptr = head;
        while (cin >> n){
                ptr = new Node;
                ptr->x = n;
                ptr->next = NULL;
                ptr = ptr->next;
        }

Comment: @Masterminder the type of `ptr`, a *pointer* to a `NodePtr`, is **critical** to this design. I tried very hard to drive that home. it isn't just a pointer, its a pointer-to-a-pointer. it is *not* the same type as `NodePtr`; it is a *pointer* to a `NodePtr`. The `head` variable is a `NodePtr`, a pointer to a `Node`. They are not the same types and therefore cannot be declared as such (which you're trying to do). Do you have some unspecified aversion to using an asterisk `*` in your code? (and if so, your ride learning pointers is going to be a bumpy one).

Comment: @Masterminder Also note, your confusion in what `NodePtr` actually represents is *the* reason why I am so adverse to using typedef'd pointer types. To me (and I assure you I'm not alone on this) it is *much* clearer to see `Node *p;` and know "thats a pointer to a Node". Likewise, seeing `Node **pp;` we can easily see "thats a pointer to a pointer to a Node". Were it up to me, `NodePtr` would not be in the code in this answer *at all*, and ultimately it would be clearer to most readers what is really going on.

Comment: Thanks a lot for breaking this down for me, I understand pointers I was just having a lot of confusion. From the examples I have been working with (in regards to pointers) they do typedefs a lot, so I understand the benefits and legibility behind Node **p vs NodePtr p. This was the solution that I was trying to implement but the line "NodePtr *ptr = &head;" was what I could not piece together at the time.

Once again thanks a lot!

Comment: @Masterminder excellent. so long as you get the jist of how pointers, and especially pointers-to-pointers (which is mandatory for understanding this solution) work, then very good. I'm glad you found the snippet useful.

Answer (score 3):

You do not actually set the 'head' variable beyond NULL(head = ptr). You you actually lose your list from the get go. Try this:

```
int n;
NodePtr head, ptr;
ptr = new Node;
head = ptr;
while (cin >> n){
    ptr->x = n;
    ptr->next = new Node;
    ptr = ptr->next;
}
```

You may then want to delete the last ptr->next and set it to 0 to save memory and avoid printing out an extra value.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So suppose I have 1 2 3 4 5 will this code create 1 2 3 4 5 plus an extra node and then I will have to set to NULL?

Comment: It's untested, but in theory yes.

Comment: How can I make it so I do not have to create the extra node? Because is that not unnecessary allocation of memory? So something like ...  1-> 2-> 3-> NULL

Comment: @Masterminder by (a) not allocating until you need to, and (b) assigning directly to the *pointer* that you want to own the new allocation. it is quite doable.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't connecting the list.  Every new item will have it's `->next` NULL.

You say `ptr = ptr->next` (which is NULL) but then the next iteration overwrites ptr with the newly allocated node.  You need to rearrange your code to string the nodes together...

One way of doing that is `ptr->next = head` makes your new node point to the old head.
Then `head = ptr` to move the head to the new node. e.g.:

To insert in the beginning (e.g. for a LIFO, last-in-first-out):

```
while (cin >> n){
    ptr = new Node;
    ptr->x = n;
    ptr->next = head;
    head = ptr;
}
```

To insert at the end (for a FIFO):

```
while (cin >> n){
    if(!head) {
        head = new Node;
        ptr = head;
    }
    else
    {
        ptr->next = new Node;
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
    ptr->next = NULL;
    ptr->x = n;
}
```

Comment: what if I want to insert at the end of the list? SO like 1 2 3 4 5 ... 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> NULL

Comment: @Masterminder.  Then you need a pointer to the head which is set when you allocate the very first node.  After that you keep a pointer to the last node similar to Quirliom's answer...  I could write this code for you but you'd enjoy it more figuring it our yourself. :-)

Comment: :D Well I know I would have to keep a pointer to the very beginning and just keep adding but what I am unsure of is that to write code so I do not have to make an unnecessary allocation, like I do not want to this 1 2 3 4 5 plus an extra node, what I want to do is 1-> 2-> 3-> 4-> 5 -> NULL

Comment: @Masterminder.  You can do that with an if statement, check if the head is NULL as a special case.  If it is, allocate new node and assign it to the head.  If it's not allocate new node in ptr->next.

Comment: I am so confused this should not be this difficult. How can I avoid creating an extra node? The if statement would be inside the loop?

Comment: @Masterminder.  Yes...  The first time you go through the loop, head is NULL.  Handle that as a special case (where you also set head to the node you allocate).  Looks like someone else decided to write this for you...

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but...
NodePtr head, ptr;
head = ptr;
means they are pointing to the same thing right?

Comment: @Masterminder: yes, assigning one pointer to another means they contain the same address which means point to the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

First, your typedef : `typedef struct Node;` is not correct. You declare a struct with the sintaxe:

```
struct st_Name{
    int field1;
    double field2;
};
```

Typedef is like a name attribution function. You should (for easier reading/working) change the name of your struct, wich is possible, after declaring it, with:

```
typedef struct Node_st Node;
```

Or, all in one statement:

```
typedef struct node_st{
  int x;
  struct node_st *next;
}Node;
```

In the segment above, notice that I also changed the `NodePtr` to `struct node_st *Next` for a reason: If you do all in one segment, since c++ code is read linearly top->down(kinda), if you try to make `NodePtr` a pointer to `Node` before the struct declaration you'll get an error, and if you do it later and use `NodePtr` inside the struct you'll also have an error. 
The compiler don't know yet that the struct exists so it will say that you're trying to name something that does not exist.

Then, your pointers manipulation is wrong.

```
...
while (cin >> n){
    ptr = new Node;
    ptr->x = n;
    ptr->next = NULL;  // You're making the next slot inexistent/NULL
    ptr = ptr->next;   // You're just setting ptr to NULL
}
...
```

What I think that you want is to keep adding to the end a keep the head in the first number. You can do this simply with an if/else statement for the first case:

```
 while (cin >> n){
     if(head == NULL){
        ptr = new Node;
        ptr->x = n;
        ptr->next = NULL;
        head = ptr;
     }else{ 
        ptr->next = new Node;
        ptr = ptr->next;
        ptr->x = n;
        ptr->next = NULL; 
     }
}
```

This way, your insertion happens in the end so your print loop should work.

Hope this helps.

Comment: so like how would a node pointer look like? I want to avoid writing "node* "

Comment: If, after the all in one declaration, you do typedef Node* NodePtr. a pointer declaration would look like NodePtr aPointer;