# List Iterator Next Function

Tags: c++

At 6 AM, I have lost the mental capacity to think through this on my own. I want to construct a function that iterates through a list using a get_next function with the following prototype;

```
list_t get_next(void);
```

Another prototype could be used as well, but that us what I've just come up with.

I am creating my own get_next function so functions provided in the list library should not be used.

Comment: Could you provide the `list_t` definition ?

Comment: You may want to return a pointer or reference instead of a value.

Answer (score 0):

It's look like linked list. If it's that you should read some articles or tutorials on it.
To start:
[Linked lists in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14544539/linked-lists-in-c)